# strtok skips more than one delimiter, how to make it skip only one

Tags: c, strtok, string.h

I am currently developing a parser for nmea sentences which typically go like this:

```
"$GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,130998,011.3,E*62\r\n"
```

So I created this function that uses strtok to parse it using the comma as delimiter and store each data field in the values array, it is important that each data field goes into the correct position in the array.

```
int split_string_by_comma (nmea_message_t * message_info, char ** values)
{
    int i = 0;
    char * p = strtok(message_info->data_field, MSG_DELIMITER);
    
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        values[i++] = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, MSG_DELIMITER);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Issue is, it is not uncommon for nmea sentences to skip certain data fields, example:

```
"$GPRMC,,A,,S,14507.36,E,000.0,,,,E*62\r\n"
```

In this case my function is useless because I want the empty data fields between the commas to be assigned to values as NULL instead of being completely ignored.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strsep`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) could be what you want:

> The strsep() function was introduced as a replacement for strtok(3), 
>  since the latter cannot handle empty fields.  
> However, strtok(3) conforms to C89/C99 and hence is more portable.

Its syntax is not exactly the same:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>

#define MSG_DELIMITER ","

void split_string_by_comma (char* msg)
{
    int i = 0;
    char * p = strsep(&msg, MSG_DELIMITER);

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d - %s\n", ++i, p);
        p = strsep(&msg, MSG_DELIMITER);
    }    
}

int main(void)
{
    char good[] = "$GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,130998,011.3,E*62\r\n";
    char bad[] = "$GPRMC,,A,,S,14507.36,E,000.0,,,,E*62\r\n";

    split_string_by_comma(good);
    split_string_by_comma(bad);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
:~/test/strsep$ ./a.out
1 - $GPRMC
2 - 081836
3 - A
4 - 3751.65
5 - S
6 - 14507.36
7 - E
8 - 000.0
9 - 360.0
10 - 130998
11 - 011.3
12 - E*62

1 - $GPRMC
2 -
3 - A
4 -
5 - S
6 - 14507.36
7 - E
8 - 000.0
9 -
10 -
11 -
12 - E*62
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to `strsep()` I was working on a system that didnt have it avaiable. Using `strtok_r()` leftover pointer address from pervious call and the tokenized address start from the current call can identify if any extra delimiters were skipped.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TOKENS    15
#define MAX_TOKEN_LEN 20

int main()
{
    
    char tokens[MAX_TOKENS][MAX_TOKEN_LEN] = { 0 };
    char str[] = "This,is,a,string,,to,be,,,split,on,comma";
    
    char *leftover;
    char *leftover_addr_start = str; // Save leftover start address
    const char *token = strtok_r(str, ",", &leftover);
    int total_tokens = 0;
    
    do {
        
        if(token != leftover_addr_start) { // Extra delimiters encountered
        
            unsigned long num_extra_delm = 
                  (unsigned long)(token - leftover_addr_start);
            
            printf("%lu Extra delimiter(s) encountered before token '%s'\n", 
                   num_extra_delm, token);
        }
        
        (void)strncpy(tokens[total_tokens], token, MAX_TOKEN_LEN); // Save Token
        printf("Tokenized - '%s'\n", tokens[total_tokens]);
        
        total_tokens++;                 // Increase Token count
        leftover_addr_start = leftover; // Save leftover start address
        
    } while((token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &leftover)) && total_tokens < MAX_TOKENS);

    return 0;
}
```